# Color ramp doesn't get applied to categories

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am following the [qgis official training guide](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#basic-fa-classifying-nominal-data), and I'm having this problem. Maybe it's because guide was done for QGIS v. 3.4 while I'm with 3.12, on Debian 10.

I have this vector layer with different classes, and I want different colors for each category in the column "landuse".

To do this, I go into layer `properties > Symbology` , I use `Categorized` for `Value: landuse` and choose a Green color ramp. I classify and what happens is that all categories have the same color, they are all dark green.

EDIT: doing the same exact process with different vector layers does the job just fine

Any idea on what may I be doing wrong here?

**This is what I'm trying to achieve:**

[image: different classes have different shades of green]

**This is what I'm having**

[image: each class has the same shade of dark green]

EDIT: this is likely a bug in QGIS 3.12, removing the layer and re-adding it seems to do the trick. It has happen also to some friends on Windows so I don't think is OS related or anything

Comment: Do you get the same result when selecting other color ramps? Or what is happening when clicking "Delete All" and "Classify"? Same result?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes I get the same result with all color ramps, and I tried to delete all and recreate several times. Weird thing is, doing the same exact thing with other vector layers works just fine.

Comment: Whan about a divergent color palette rather than a sequential one?